# How to add a UTF-8 String of JSON within JSON in Curl?

Tags: json, facebook, scala, curl, playframework

I'm creating a menu for my Facebook bot by posting some JSON to their API. The payload is required to be a UTF-8 string. I would like this string to be JSON such that my server can read it easily. The following results in the error "setting_type" is required which indicates something is not being escaped properly:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type" : "call_to_actions",
  "thread_state" : "existing_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"Schedule",
      "payload":"{"action":"schedule"}"
    },
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"Cancel",
      "payload":"{"action":"cancel"}"
    },
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"View",
      "payload":"{"action":"view"}"
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=TOKEN"
```

A solution is to escape the double quotes inside the payload:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type" : "call_to_actions",
  "thread_state" : "existing_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"Schedule",
      "payload":"{\"action\":\"schedule\"}"
    },
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"Cancel",
      "payload":"{\"action\":\"cancel\"}"
    },
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"View",
      "payload":"{\"action\":\"view\"}"
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=TOKEN"
```

This succeeds. However when the payload is sent to me it looks like this:

```
"payload":"{\"action\":\"schedule\"}"}
```

and thus does not parse properly.

**UPDATE**

I've written the same procedure in Scala using the Play! framework:

```
def getMenuJson(greeting: String, schedule: String, cancel: String, view: String)(implicit sd: String): JsValue = {
    log.info(Json.toJson(BotPayload("schedule", None)).toString())
    val menu = Outgoing(
      Recipient(sd),
      OutMessage(
        Some(OutAttachment(
          "template",
          Payload("button", greeting, List(
            Button("postback", None, Some(schedule), Some(Json.toJson(BotPayload("schedule", None)).toString())),
            Button("postback", None, Some(cancel), Some(Json.toJson(BotPayload("cancel", None)).toString())),
            Button("postback", None, Some(view), Some(Json.toJson(BotPayload("view", None)).toString()))
          ))
        )), None)
    )
    Json.toJson(menu)
  }
```

The log statement that appears at the top of the function outputs:

```
{"action":"schedule"}
```

which implies the JSON in payload is correctly being formatted as a string. Now when a user presses the schedule button from Facebook I get back for the payload:

```
"payload":"{\"action\":\"schedule\"}"
```

So perhaps the second Curl command was fine and I just need to deal with parsing the JSON with escaped quotes.

**UPDATE 2**

Working on parsing the result. This isn't quite working:

```
  implicit val botPayloadReads: Reads[BotPayload] = (
    (JsPath \ """\"action\"""").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ """"\"returnToAction\"""").readNullable[String]
    )(BotPayload.apply _)
```

Error:

```
List((/entry(0)/messaging(0)/postback/payload/\"action\",List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))))
```

Comment: you could use sed to modify your escaping before you send it

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: sure, sed is a unix tool for text replacement.  so you'd need to build some regex to parse and replace what you want for escaping.  this is not an ideal way of dealing with JSON though.

Comment: I think you are either supposed to parse the string value of `payload` *again*, or the value of `payload` is supposed to be an object, not a string.

Comment: Payload must be a UTF-8 string.

Comment: Curl is probably just a hard way to deal with this problem.

Comment: What happens if you exclude the call_to_actions key and value?

Comment: It tells me I am missing the structured menu (which is defined by the call to actions).

Comment: You know what I think the second way I did it is correct. When I handle this problem in Scala Facebook sends me back "payload":"{\"action\":\"schedule\"}"} also. I have verified that scala is sending out the payload string: {"action":"schedule"}.

Comment: I don't see any code relevant to parsing what comes back in Play.

Comment: @m-z Correct I am only addressing the question of whether I should be getting back the result in question at this point. I'll add it.